# Checking the memory requested two times

Tags: c, malloc, free

There is one thing which I'm not sure, hence the Question now, I hope that the title is OK here.

Lets check the following program first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char *fn;
};

int main(void){
    struct person *pers;

    pers = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if(pers == NULL){
        printf("No memory Avaible\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pers->fn = malloc(10000000000000000); /*requesting a big chunk*/
    if(pers->fn == NULL){
        printf("No memory Avaible =>> [pers->fn]\n");
        free(pers);
        exit(2);
    }


    strcpy(pers->fn, "Michi");
    pers->fn[strlen(pers->fn)] = '\0';

    printf("FN = %s\n",pers->fn);

    if(pers->fn){
        free(pers->fn);
    }

    if(pers){
        free(pers);
    }
}
```

The Output would be:

```
No memory Avaible =>> [pers->fn]
```

Because there is no memory available, I  do a free on the `pers` and then `exit`:

```
if(pers->fn == NULL){
    printf("No memory Avaible =>> [pers->fn]\n");
    free(pers);
    exit(2);
}
```

Now lets say that we have enough memory and the program works fine, latter we come to this part:

```
if(pers->fn){
    free(pers->fn);
}

if(pers){
    free(pers);
}
```

Is there any guarantee that I should check if the memory is still there? 
Or I'm just fine with:

```
free(pers->fn);
free(pers);
```

Comment: The only reason the memory wouldn't be there is if you, or someone else, had freed it for you.  As you are exiting on bad assign, the value has to be there.  I'd only if check if there was a chance that someone else had changed or freed it for you.  BTW, `10000000000000000` overflows the malloc int, but I am sure you are aware of that :)

Comment: Since your program unconditionally exits if **malloc()** is unsuccsesful, there is no reason to check on exit.  Other programs could have a different flow of logic, and may need checks at exit.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I had somehow to simulate :))

Comment: @ArifBurhan The other part was the question, because I already know that `malloc` succeded, so I need to know if there is a guaranty here and there is no need to check it again

Comment: This is starting to feel like a question about style -- rather than a question about specific code. Are you asking a "general" question about whether stylistically you should always check before calling `free()` (because you've seen others do it), or are you trying to verify the code you shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to check at that point in the program. You could only get there if the the two previous `malloc()`s were a success.

Comment: Based on the fact, that malloc succeeded there is no need to check that memory again...Yes that I know already, but the Question is about if there is 100% sure/safe, if not, what could be the cause of that.

Comment: There is no such thing as 100% sure/safe. The CPU could be damaged, you could have bad RAM or malware could find some clever way to cross over system protections and invade your programs memory space. But in the C code you shared, you are 100% sure/safe that the code is valid and needs no further checking before calling `free()`

Comment: This kind of Answer I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `free()` with either a valid pointer to memory that was allocated via `malloc()`, or with a zero value. Therefore, so long as your pointer is either valid or NULL, you don't have to check before calling `free()`.

Comment: This I know already, but the Question is about something else here. Please check @MichaelDorgan's comment.